# how to add ICQ account to empathy?

Tags: gnome

I am new to linux and i just installed ubuntu 12.10 with gnome 3.6. Now I am trying to setup my accounts. I have a problem because I want to use ICQ with the in GNOME integrated IM system, i.e. message popup automatically and you can answer them from the bottomt status bar.

So how can I add ICQ support to the system? I already installed "telepathy-haze" from the ubuntu software but there is no ICQ option in the settings->accounts window. also, there are two account (german language: "Online-Konten") in the system->personal window. Did I install gnome wrong? or is that normal?

I really like the look and feel of ubuntu + gnome3.6 but right now I feel that it is not working they way it is supposed to. any help?

Comment: I always used a different messenger called "Pidgin". It offers much more account flexibility.

Comment: I am using that one as well now but it kind of defeats the purpose of having this integration into the OS if I can use my favourite IM system with it and instead have to use a third party app for it. or is there a way to inegrate pidging into the statusbar->user menu and the those fancy popup messages when a new msg arrives? ;)

Comment: There are ways, in Pidgin's options, but please don't come after me if I'm wrong - I'm not 100% here, so I couldn't offer an actual answer. All I'm suggesting is technically a work-around anyways.

I use many IM protocols together, which is why I suggested Pidgin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add ICQ account to empathy. You need to download a plugin.

Here is the steps:

Open terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install account-plugin-icq
```

Now open empathy and click on add account. You will be able to see ICQ on the list.

[image]

Comment: is there a list to all the plugins we can use